# Detecting if user like facebook app

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying for hours now to check if the current user is "liked" my app.
I do require "user_likes" permission on login but even when I'm clicking the like button, when I check if the user like the app with isFan or with FQL I still get zero likes!

this is how I'm trying to get if the user "liked" the app:

```
$isFan = $facebook->api(array(
  "method"    => "pages.isFan",
  "page_id"   => xxxxx,
  "uid"       => $session
));

if($isFan === TRUE)
  echo "I'm a fan!";
```

OR

```
$likes = $facebook->api(array(
  'method' => 'fql.query', 
  'query' => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='xxxxx' AND uid='$session'", 
));

print  'likes found: ' . count($likes) . '<br />';
```

both methods gives me nothing, please if some one can help me it will be great!

Thanks!
Moti

Comment: can you provide the code where you set $session please?

Comment: this is how I set the session: $session = $facebook-> getUser();

Comment: Have you tried testing this out manually [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/) on the Facebook docs?

Comment: thanks for the link! I just tested it and getting "false" but I did pressed the "Like" button with that user....  it's maybe the away i added the "like" button ? i added it through this page:http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ .. this is the first time i'm trying to do app for facebook..

Comment: another thing, i set my application id as the page ID parameter is that ok ?

Comment: You want to you the page ID instead of the app ID. To get the page ID, go to the page you want and the url should look like this: https://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE_NAME/PAGE_ID this is your page id. Try that. If it isn't a facebook page then go to https://graph.facebook.com/?id=PAGE_URL and it will tell you the PAGE_ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the Page ID instead of the App ID. I'm not sure if your page is a Facebook Page (facebook.com/pages/ **[PAGE_NAME]** / **[PAGE_ID]** ) or if you have a non-Facebook page.

Obviously if you have a Facebook page then the number on the end of the URL will be your Page ID. Otherwise if you have a non-Facebook page you can use the graph to get your Page ID.

> https://graph.facebook.com/?id= **[PAGE_URL]**

Use that ID instead of the app ID and it should give you the correct result. To be sure try it out with the tool on the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/)

Comment: my application goes like :http://apps.facebook.com/MY_APPLICATION_NAME and no page id is supplied.. any ideas?

Comment: Where did you put the like button? That is the page you need the ID for.

Comment: I put it in the index.php page.. but still i don't see the page name.. only the apps.face.... with the name i gave my application

Comment: OK, thanks a lot squinlan, I used what you suggested "    https://graph.facebook.com/?id= [PAGE_URL]" it finally gave me true value!!, thanks a lot.. is there a way to rate you here??

Answer (score 2):

Is your page public?  From the link posted in the comments by squinlan:

> If the user's pages are set to less than everyone privacy, you must ask the user for the user_likes extended permission and include a valid user access token in the API call.

So when you go though the authorisation process as [documented here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), you will finally be issued with an access token.  You then append that to any requests you make to ensure the correct permission is granted:

```
$isFan = $facebook->api(array(
  "method"       => "pages.isFan",
  "page_id"      => xxxxx,
  "uid"          => $session,
  "access_token" => $access_token
));
```

Comment: I did asked for "user_likes" permissions .. i also checked it with the: hasAppPermission methods and it gives me "true" so no problem there/

Comment: you have the permission, but are you sending the access token along with your request?

Comment: no... i just understand it too.. how do i send it? can you please give me example?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot shanethehat, I did tried it with the token and I still get "False" I think it's because i need to provide the PageID and not the ApplicationID, but I don't know how to get the page ID, its should be at the address bar but it's not, my application start with :http://apps.facebook.com/MY_APPLICATION_NAME, any ideas?