# Why I cannot get facebook like my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

What I want to do is user must like my page first then only can go to my `facebook apps`, but I have no idea why I cannot detect it and I had `var_dump` my page liked, result is **NULL**

here is my code

```
$request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $load) = explode('.', $request, 2);
$fbData = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($load, '-_', '+/')), true);

var_dump($fbData["page"]["liked"]);// output is NULL

if (!empty($fbData["page"]["liked"]))
{ 
  echo "This content is for Fans only!";
} else {
  echo "Please click on the Like button to view this tab!";
}
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: make sure you are not issuing any redirection otherwise the `signed_request` will be lost. More [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page/5331541#5331541). also `var_dump($request);` to see what you are going to get.

Answer (score 0):

You need the permission `user_likes` to check if they liked your **Facebook App** but $fbData["page"]["liked"] is referring to your **Facebook App Page** which is seperate.

To edit your App Page go to App Settings > Advanced > Near the bottom you will see **App Page**

To use the permission user_likes to check see this [SO Answer On Detecting if a User Likes a Facebook App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866684/detecting-if-user-like-facebook-app)

Comment: No you don’t, not when getting the info from the signed_request.

Comment: thank for reply, I new on facebook developer, can you provide me more detail information? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure there **is** as signed_request parameter?

It only gets transmitted to your app once the page is initially loaded into the Facebook iframe – it won’t be there anymore once you start navigating inside your app.

Best thing to do IMHO is to parse the signed_request if not empty, and safe the results into your own session.

Btw., parsing it yourself is rather time-consuming – I’d suggest using the PHP SDK and use Facebook::getSignedRequest() – that method gives you all the data in decoded form, if there was a signd_request parameter.

So here’s what I usually do:

```
if($signed_request_data = $Facebook->getSignedRequest()) {
  $_SESSION['signed_request_data'] = $signed_request_data;
}
```

You can call that code on every page – only if the method actually returns data, your session gets updated.

Comment: hi CBroe, thank for reply,  I new on facebook developer, can you provide me more detail information such as some link or code? thanks

Comment: Please read the documentation! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getSignedRequest/ for a start; also have a look around in the whole developer area to get a grasp of the basic concepts.